# Obtaining System Log using Okta API

Tags: api, okta

I would like to do the following using OKTA api:

- One time, I would like to pull the entire system log.
- Going forward I would like to pull only the days log information.

The challenge that I am facing is whenever I get the logs, I only get 1000 records. How do I get the whole days log, it maybe more that 1000 records. Is there some body who can help me with a piece of code which shows how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1000 is the default limit for the Events API because this object can potentially contain a lot of data.

However, you can specify how many records for a specific time range are returned via the Events API using filters. For example, the following GET statement would retrieve the first 100 successful login requests since 1-Mar.

https://{{YOUR_COMPANY}}.okta.com/api/v1/events?limit=100&filter=published gt "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" and action.objectType eq “core.user_auth.login_success"

If there are more than 100 records, you can get the next set by passing rel=“next” in the next request header. If you wanted to get only messages for today, you could change the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Events API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/rest/events.html) to retrieve this information. This API supports [Pagination](http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/design_principles.html#pagination) so you can retrieve all the events for a particular filter (like all events after a certain point in time).